# linq select query?

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by

ChartData

```
public class ChartData {
    public Series[] Series { get; set; }
}
```

Series

```
public class Series{
    public Strind Name { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Data

```
public class Data {
    public object[] Points { get; set; }
}
```

Records

```
 Date | Name | Value

date1 | T1  |    15
date1 | T2  |    20
date2 | T1  |    25
date2 | T2  |    30
date3 | T1  |    35
date3 | T2  |    40
```

And linq codes

```
(from d in MeterReadings
 group d by new { name = d.Name } into g
 select new ChartData
 {
     Series = (from s in g
              select new Series
              {
                  Name = g.Key.name,
                  Data = new Data(new object[] { g.Select(x => x.Value) })
              }).ToArray()
     }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Expected:

```
Name = T1 , Data = 15, 25, 35
Name = T2 , Data = 20, 30, 40
```

But Output:

```
Name = T1 , Data = 15, 25, 35
Name = T1 , Data = 15, 25, 35
Name = T1 , Data = 15, 25, 35
```

I cant find right codes to get expected. Could you review the linq codes? Where have done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why did you use FirstOrDefault? it returns only the first row.

Comment: you can't return the first row and expect your desire output......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you select new `ChartData` for each grouping and then take first. Try this code:

```
var series =  MeterReadings.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                           .Select(g => new Series
                            {
                                Name = g.Key,
                                Data = new Data {Points = g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()}
                            })
                           .ToArray();
var chartData = new ChartData {Series = series};
```

Comment: result is the same like mine.